# VS Code Extension Dependencies Not Installing

Tags: visual-studio-code

Per the documentation available at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest, setting an `"extensionDependencies"` key in the `package.json` for an extension is supposed to install any dependencies along with your own extension, but it seems like this isn't working for me. My `package.json` specifies the following:

```
"extensionDependencies": [
        "ms-vccode.cpptools",
        "ms-python.python"
    ]
```

and yet when I try to test the extension, I get the error:

```
Cannot activate extension 'my-extension' because it depends on extension 'ms-vccode.cpptools', which is not installed or disabled. Please install or enable 'ms-vccode.cpptools' and reload the window.
```

Is there a way to ensure these extensions do get installed automatically when installing my own? Thanks!